# Интерпретатор говорит, что не существует индекса с именем файла, хотя файл был передан - Notice: Undefined index image

Tags: php, файлы, form, изображения

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="<?php $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/formdata">
     <p>Выберите файл для загрузки: <br>
      <input type="file" name="image">
     </p>
     <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
    </form>

    <?php
     if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
         $name = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
         $temp_name = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
         $size = $_FILES["image"]["size"];

         $ext = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
         $ext = strtolower($ext);

         if ($ext != "png" && $ext != "jpg" && $ext != "gif") {
             echo "Изображение должно быть в формате PNG, JPG (JPEG) или GIF.<br>";
             exit();
         }

         if ($size > 512000) {
             echo "Размер файла не должен превышать 512 Кб.<br>";
             exit();
         }

         if (file_exists($name)) {
             echo "Файл с именем $name уже был выгружен.<br>";
             exit();
         }
         try {
             move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $name);
             echo "Файл $name  выгружен:<br>";
             echo '<img src= "' . $name . '"';
         }
         catch(Exception $e) {
             echo "Файл $name не может быть выгружен.<br>";
         }
     }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Загружаю изображение, потом нажимаю отправить и выводятся ошибки для строк кода, где переменным $name, $tmp_name и $size присваиваются значения. Ошибки такие: Notice: Undefined index image

НОВАЯ ПРОБЛЕМА:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="<?php $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <p>Выберите файл для выгрузки: <br>
      <input type="file" name="image">
     </p>
     <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
    </form>

    <?php
     if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
         $name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
         $temp_name = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
         $size = $_FILES["image"]["size"];

         $ext = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
         $ext = strtolower($ext);
        try {
         if ($ext != "png" && $ext != "jpg" && $ext != "gif") {
             throw new Exception("Изображение должно быть в формате PNG, JPG (JPEG) или GIF.<br>");
         }

         if ($size > 512000) {
             throw new Exception("Размер файла не должен превышать 512 Кб.<br>");
         }

         if (file_exists($name)) {
             throw new Exception("Файл уже был выгружен!<br>");
         }

             move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $name);
             echo "Файл $name  выгружен:<br>";
             echo '<img src= " '. $name .' "';
        }
         catch(Exception $e) {
             echo $e->getMessage();
         }
     }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Всё время срабатывает исключение Файл уже был выгружен!

Comment: @РустамГимранов в моём учебнике написано formdata. В других источниках увидел, что надо писать form-data. В обоих случаях не работает :\

Comment: @РустамГимранов можете пожалуйста поподробнее объяснить? Я не совсем понимаю к чему Вы это говорите

Comment: @РустамГимранов у меня действительно по какой-то причине отрабатывает строка echo "Изображение должно быть в формате PNG, JPG (JPEG) или GIF.<br>"; НО: почему это происходит если загружен файл .jpg? И у меня вылезают 3 ошибки notice: undefined index image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1** Поменять `enctype="multipart/formdata"` на `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. Информация о загрузке файла на сервер [тут](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.post-method.php).

**2** Проверка расширения файла при помощи `pathinfo` никак не безопасна. Цитата с сайта www.php.net:

> Не используйте ... для проверки того, что файл является файлом с изображением. Для этих целей используйте расширение [Fileinfo](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.fileinfo.php).

На *stackoverflow* есть множество хороших примеров по загрузке файла на сервер.

**3** Начало конструкции `try...catch` можно поднять выше:

```
...
$size = $_FILES["image"]["size"];

try {

  if ($size > 512000) {
    throw new \Exception('Размер файла не должен превышать 512 Кб.');
  }

... Тут остальные проверки и загрузка.

} catch (\Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо) Теперь Notice: Undefined index image не выдает

Comment: Но каждый раз при попытке загрузки какого-либо файла, даже того, который я вообще никогда не пытался загружать, срабатывает проверка на то, что файл уже был загружен. Помогите пожалуйста с этой проблемой

Comment: ок, сейчас обновлю в вопросе

Comment: я обновил вопрос

Comment: Ясно, большое спасибо)